# Unknown provider with 2 Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the famous `Unknown provider` error with my node app and can't figure out why.

app.js

`var app = angular.module('citigraph', ['addCtrl', 'mygservice', 'stationservice']);`

addCtrl.js

```
var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrl', ['mygservice', 'rzModule', 'chart.js', 'stationservice']);
addCtrl.controller('addCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, gservice, stationservice){ ... }
```

stationservice.js

```
angular.module('stationservice', []).service('mystationservice', function($http){ ... }
```

The error in detail:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: stationserviceProvider <-
>   stationservice <- addCtrl

Comment: @Igor Tried already, leads to `Module 'stationservice' is not available! You either misspelled ... `

Comment: It looks like you are not using modules correctly. Why do you create a new module for every service/component, etc you want to use? Use a single module name and reuse that module. You can retrieve it again by name if you omit the 2nd set of parameters. Let me know if there is a good reason you do want to create a new module for every registration...

Comment: @Igor No there isn't, I learned this from a tutorial, not sure what the intention was. So just have app.js like it is, and in the other ones replace 'addCtrl' and 'stationservice' with 'citigraph'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not using modules correctly. Use a single module name and reuse that module. You can retrieve it again by name if you omit the 2nd set of parameters.

You could create multiple modules but that is generally done when you want to group multiple items together as a piece of functionality.

app.js

```
// add common external dependencies to this module to the [] array
var app = angular.module('citigraph', []);
```

addCtrl.js

```
// add controller to same module
var app = angular.module('citigraph');
app.controller('addCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'gservice', 'stationservice', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, gservice, stationservice){ ... }]
```

stationservice.js

```
// add service to same module
angular.module('citigraph').service('mystationservice', ['$http', function($http){ ... }]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will adapt this.

Comment: Okay finally got it. In addition to all of this, the order of the services/factories included in the html file also matters in a way I didn't grasp yet. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ffritz - yes, sorry I did not realize you still having issues. Just in case you should probably also specify the names in your injections because as soon as you minify your javascript files (if you ever decide to bundle/minify/uglify them) then your code will break.

Comment: No worries. That is good to know, as I do want to minify it later.

Comment: @ffritz - I updated the code with how to do that for when you get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below. I think there is some mix up here. Why do you need create two modules for application if they can be combined together.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('citigraph', []);
```

addCtrl.js

```
 var app = angular.module('addCtrl');
    app.controller('addCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, gservice, stationservice){ ... }
```

stationservice.js

```
angular.module('citigraph').service('mystationservice', function($http){ ... }
```

Please refer Angular JS official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di for more information.